# How can we check the UILabel value in KIF

Tags: ios, swift, kif

I have a UILabel with value "text".

Now in KIF I tried to check its value by using:

```
(UIView *)waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:(NSString *)label value:(NSString *)value traits:(UIAccessibilityTraits)traits
```

But it failed saying:

> The step timed out after 10.00 seconds

I found an accessibility element with the label "myLabel", but with the value is "(null)", not "text".

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Help the community and your self by posting your solution by answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check the value to prevent that test failure.

It's likely that your UIAccessibilityTrait parameter is wrong. For instance, if your accessibility item is a Button, `traits:` should be UIAccessibilityTraitButton.

You can check the `Traits` in the Accessibility Inspector.